# Google Gmail Addons card doesn't refresh after OAuth 2.0 authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-workspace-add-ons

I am developing the addon for Google Gmail and I use Google Apps Script. Also I use OAuth2 lib. After authorization success path card doesn't refresh and I can't see actual content.

Code:

```
function getClient(): GoogleAppsScriptOAuth2.OAuth2Service | null {
...
 return OAuth2.createService('myService')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(
      `${url}/${prefix}/oauth2-token/authorize`
    )
    .setTokenUrl(`${url}/oauth2-token`)
    .setClientId(clientId)
    .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .setCallbackFunction('handleOAuthResponse')
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
    .setLock(LockService.getUserLock())
    .setGrantType('authorization_code');
}

function handleOAuthResponse(request: Record<string, any>) {
  const client = getClient();

  const authorized = client.handleCallback(request);

  if (authorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied.');
  }
}
```

I checked some available addons in Google Shop (like Zoom, Dropbox etc.) and they have the same problem.
How I can refresh a card after success authorization?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I found out that Safari works fine. But Firefox, Edge and Google Chrome have that bug.

That looks like additional refresh in "Chrome engine" browsers